# dd utility number of passes on bad block

Tags: macos, unix, dd, ddrescue

In ddrescue you can set how many times to try to read from bad block (ddrescue -r1 will try once). It does not seem to be the case with dd.

Does anybody know how many times dd tries bad blocks?

Thanks

Comment: why down vote??

Answer (score 1):

`dd` is not designed for error recovery, which is why `ddrescue` was created.

So the short answer is: `dd` tries just once to read a block. It assumes that the hardware is in working order, just like most other utilities such as `cat`, `cp`, `sort`, etc.

When `dd` encounters an error, it will terminate unless you have specified `conv=noerror`.